# iOS wait for pdf to generate and attach to email

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, objective-c-blocks, completion-block

I am generating a pdf from html and attaching to email. The problem I have is the pdf is attaching to the email before it has finished generating. 
I have tried using a completion block but without success.

```
 @property (nonatomic, strong) void(^completionHandler)(BOOL);
```

```
[self generatePDF:html andCompletionHandler:^(BOOL result) {            
// COMPLETED ? - ATTACH the file  

                    NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
                    NSString *pdfPathFile=[docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/report.pdf"];
                    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfPathFile];
                    [controller setMessageBody:@"report attached" isHTML:NO];
                    [controller addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"report.pdf"];
                    NSLog(@"attaching pdf with length %d",[pdfData length]);

                }];
```

```
-(void)generatePDF:(NSMutableString*)HtmlString andCompletionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL result))handler{

_completionHandler = handler;

NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];


NSString *pdfPathFile=[docDir stringByAppendingString:@"/report.pdf"];

NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError *error;

if ([fm fileExistsAtPath:pdfPathFile] == YES){
    [fm removeItemAtPath:pdfPathFile error:&error];
}
//I am using NDHTMLtoPDF to create the PDF

 self.PDFCreator = [NDHTMLtoPDF createPDFWithHTML:HtmlString pathForPDF:pdfPathFile delegate:self pageSize:kPaperSizeA4 margins:UIEdgeInsetsMake(10,5,10,5)];

}

#pragma mark NDHTMLtoPDFDelegate

- (void)HTMLtoPDFDidSucceed:(NDHTMLtoPDF*)htmlToPDF
{

NSString *result = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTMLtoPDF did succeed - %@", htmlToPDF.PDFpath];
NSLog(@"%@",result);

_completionHandler(YES);

}
```

Comment: What specifically is failing with this code?

Comment: I don't really see why you're using a block here. You should just have the didSucceed delegate method either start the mail composition itself or have it call another method that does that.

Comment: Can you please show us the code where you present the `MFMailComposeViewController` instance? I think, you have some buggy lines of code there.

Comment: if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
 {
  // set the sendTo address
  NSMutableArray *recipients = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
  [recipients addObject:email];
  
  MFMailComposeViewController *controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        
  [controller setSubject:subject];
  [controller setToRecipients:recipients];

Comment: Specifically, The email is being displayed without the pdf attachment.